# Can't load the class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: java, mysql, eclipse, jdbc

I have read all the prior answers and followed (on Eclipse) Build Path -> Configure Build Path to add the external JAR: mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar, however, it's still can not load the class.

My servlet code:

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
  PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
  try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    out.println("<br>Class loaded: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver<br>");
  } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    out.println("<br>Can't load class: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver<br>");
    return;
  }
}
```

My Eclipse verson: Luna Release (4.4.0)
Ny OSX: 10.9.4

Anybody has a clue?

Comment: Can you describe your problem more specifically? The basic way to add external *.jar to the Eclipse project is by doing right click on the project e.g. in the `Package Explorer` view, than choosing "Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs...". After this, all classes from the added *.jar should be added to the project's default classpath.

Answer (score 1):

As the above method is `protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)` I think that we can assume that this is a web application.

When deploying the application to Tomcat (???) ensure that the jar is included either in tomcat/lib or in the deployed WEB-INF/lib directory

**EDIT:** as per @duffymo 
Tomcat 7.x requires that the JAR be in the Tomcat /lib directory or it won't find it.

Comment: Tomcat 7.x requires that the JAR be in the Tomcat /lib directory or it won't find it.

Comment: @duffymo Thanks, I thought that may be the case.

Answer (score 0):

You just config that for Build Path in Eclipse for compiling.
When running it in Servlet Container like Tomcat, you need to put in WEB-INF/lib.

Putting jar file under Tomcat lib folder will also work.

Comment: See Tomcat 7.x: "The JRE Memory Leak Prevention Listener that is included with Apache Tomcat solves this by triggering the drivers scan during Tomcat startup. This is enabled by default. It means that only libraries visible to the listener such as the ones in $CATALINA_BASE/lib will be scanned for database drivers. If you are considering disabling this feature, note that the scan would be triggered by the first web application that is using JDBC, leading to failures when this web application is reloaded and for other web applications that rely on this feature."

Comment: I also think putting DB Driver jar file under container is not a good idea. It is part of the application and stays in application.

Comment: The writers of Tomcat disagree with you.  The app server usually manages connection pools, so the drivers need to be accessible to its class loader.  This is true across applications.

Comment: When running locally, I will put driver class into my App, but when using App Server like WebSphere, WebLogic which usually have these driver jar files, I will let App servers to manage connection pools.